# Import flat-file fixed width - suggestions

Tags: perl, powershell, flat-file, fixed-width

I am reading a flat file (fixed width fields) so that I can import it into SQLServer. This is a new project in my company. I have not yet worked on parsing huge files in the most time-efficient and quick way. Scouring on the Internet, I have found a powershell script which can parse a fixed-width file... It does the job of parsing the file.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 

$Parser = New-Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser( 
'C:\T1046436.dat') 

$Parser.TextFieldType = 'FixedWidth' 
$Parser.TrimWhiteSpace = $False 
$Parser.FieldWidths = @(13,6,11,2,10,10,1,1,7,7,2,17,1,2,2,4,1,10,10,10,10,2,10,10,11,2,2,1,1) 

while(!$Parser.EndOfData) 
{ 
try 
{ 
    Write-Host $Parser.ReadFields() 
} 
catch [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException] 
{ 
    Write-Host "Error, line $($_.Exception.LineNumber): $($Parser.ErrorLine)" 
} 
}
```

I want to be able to save this in a pipe-delimited file, so that I can simply BCP IN the sql database. Thats my quick-dirty way to load data. But, it is using lots of time (20 minutes for 50000 records).

Any suggestions to get it quickly/ efficiently:

- converted into pipe-delimited file
  OR
- directly import the flat file into SQL server from powershell...
  OR
- I am open to use any other scripting language which can help parse the flat-file quickly into a pipe-delimited file (python, perl etc) under Windows. Any example scripts to use will be appreciated.

Comment: You should include sample .dat file and sample of wanted result(ex. you're not saving anything in the script above). Also, you should NEVER use `Write-Host` to output data. `Write-Host` is for text, and will only work in an interactive sessions(console). Just use `$Parser.ReadFields()` or `Write-Output $Parser.Readfields()` to output the data.

Comment: @Graimer: The reason I did not post any sample data as I was abler to parse the data without issues (as in the data was parsed as expected). Here it is:

`0027322230415367691294302160A 102012-05-082012-06-143342731  ~         0000000001929.51 39070000~1134117849~         1750319562~         2 2012-09-072012-09-10294302160A ~ ~ 95
0030799704021360025281074647A 402013-03-252013-03-2913V5789  ~      N  0000000000000.00 3930000031801884655~         1851370175~         1 2013-05-032013-05-06281074647A ~ ~ 00
0028707039287360025580907416A 402012-11-282012-11-281353510  ~         0000000001111.17`

Comment: Expected output is the same data in a pipe-delimited format.

Comment: Can you please share an example to save data in a file using write-output?

Comment: Powershell isn't meant for processing data in volumes like this. Do you know any other programming languages? You have tagged your question with both Perl and Python. If you can use either of these then your program would run very much faster

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, I understand powershell is not the way to go, but, that was a quick/ dirty step for me to get started. Can you help with any example of perl/ python? I am not an expert at Perl/ Python, but, can figure out things if I can get a head-start.... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To save you could do something like `$Parser.ReadFields() -join "|" | Out-File test.csv` Since you're using `.Net` classes anyways, why not just compile a console application? You've almost completed it already with the code above.

Comment: What languages *do* you know? Write something in Perl, Python, or a sensible language of your choice. If you can't get it to work then show it in a new question and you will get help to finish it. It isn't fair to come here expecting us to do your work.

Comment: Well, nothing to do with answering the question, but this question is the only place where I seen the use of `TextFieldParser` with `FixedWidth`, so thanks! Upvoted the question just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Powershell script will parse a collection of $files containing records of 5 fields, each having 10 characters, and output those records with the fields pipe-delimited.

```
#Create a regular expression to match the field widths and capture the data.
$regex = [regex]'(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})'

#create a filter to insert a pipe character between the captured groups.
filter PipeDelimit {$_ -replace $regex, '$1|$2|$3|$4|$5'}


#Pipe the records thorough the filter in batches of 1000 
Get-Content $files -ReadCount 1000 | Pipedelimit
```

You'll need to modify the regex and filter to match your data. I suspect it will take considerably less than 20 minutes to chew through half a million of those records.

The `-Readcount` will control memory usage by keeping only 1000 records at a time in the pipeline. They will be passed to the pipeline as an array, and the `-replace` operator in the filter will delimit the entire array in one operation, without needing to `foreach` through each record.  The `filter` is admittedly unusual, and could be replaced with `foreach-object`, but the `filter` is marginally faster and it adds up if you're doing lots of reps.

Comment: That is presumably PowerShell? You should say so, and provide at least a little commentary on the code.

Comment: Much. Thank you. I would perfect it by using markdown to identify code within your paragraphs, but this is pretty good.

Comment: Will that get close to what Perl or Python will do?

Comment: @mjolinor: This is awesome. I can run through the 50000 records file in 2 minutes... When I redirect output to a text, its less than 30 seconds for 50000 records.

Comment: What is a quick/ dirty fix to write a static number towards the end of each row (which represents a batchid)?

Comment: There's probably two or three different ways to do that, and that proably needs to be a new question so other people can weigh in with answers.

Comment: Sure thing. will create another question to get feedback.